# Challenging Rails Question with Form Based on Existing Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations

You have a set of related models created through a scaffold e.g. a *house*, which has many *rooms*, which each have many *windows*, which each has a selection of *locks*.
These resources are already full of data i.e. someone has entered all the information, such as: a room called 'kitchen' has various windows associated with it and these windows each have five different locks associated with them.

Someone comes along and says:

> Can you create a form that lets someone create a new project where they can select the different rooms, windows and then specify the locks that they would like for that project? *(these are already in the system, nothing new to add, just the associations to a new project)*

This sounds like a nested form but I have wasted a lot of time trying to solve this - there are many levels of nesting, which make this tricky. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should change your title to pertain to your question.

Comment: @J Lundberg, I have updated it.

Comment: I've just added a bounty on this.  If it needs further clarification please let me know :)

Comment: I think one thing should be cleared out in your example. Is every room unique to a house (as in parent has_many children) or is it a HBTM or has_many through relation (as in order has many products through items selected) because in the first case the scope of choice should be limited and can be resolved with (enhanced) select box, wheras if its the 2nd type of relationship select box are usually a bad idea...

Comment: @charlysisto, it is as per your second example i.e. like an order having many products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### session based solution

With such deeply nested models select box on the front end wouldn't be enough... 
Assuming this, you may want to create a current_house who's id live in a session (just like current_user works).

Once you have your current_house add different items by navigating to your list of items view and clicking on the add_to link :

```
  # house_controller.rb
  def add_to
    current_house.polymorphic_items << Kitchen.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

But there are many approaches to this session based solution which sort of implements a cart/order system. You may want to add a current_item to add stuff in each leaf of your tree aka room of your house.

E.G after clicking on the kitchen you just added :

```
before_filter :set_current_item

def add_to
  current_item.windows << Window.find(id)
end
```

current_item beeing polymorphic : a living room, a bathroom etc.
But how you implement that precisely depends on your Domain Model....

As a rule of thumb regarding nested forms I'd follow rails guidance for routes : don't go deeper than one level or you'll end up in a mess.

Comment: Thanks.  I like the idea of not going down further than 1 level.  Would a series of forms that get submitted by a master form be a way around it? (perhaps by using Ajax and partials)

Comment: Indeed an [autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) to pull down data with callback to call deeper nested data would help. But I would try to make it work without js 1st (to gracefully degrade). Also you can consider using the [presenter and the conductor pattern](http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2007/8/31/presenters-conductors-on-rails) but I admit I have never used them yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a nested form. [Railscasts nested forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) is a great place to start.

If everything is already in the system you probably just want select boxes so they can select what they want. Also check out the .build method. If you have multiple levels of nesting you can also manually set the association by passing in the foreign key yourself.

Comment: How would this be populated with existing data?  All I need to do is build the associations and not enter new data like your example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can model this with a single level of nested attributes, given the models below (based on Windows/Locks pre-existing and a room just needing to mix and match them into a set of windows with given locks):

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rooms
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :house
  has_many :window_configs
end

class WindowConfig < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :window
  belongs_to :lock
end

class Lock < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :window_configs
end

class Window < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :window_configs
end
```

... based on that model setup, you could have a single house form that you dynamically add child 'room' definitions to that each have a name and a collection of window_configs which have two select boxes for each one (choose a window definition and then a lock definition).  Because you're dynamically adding multiple rooms with multiple windows, you'd need some JS to populate new form elements, but it could all live in a single nested form.

```
form_for :house do |form|
  # Dynamically add a Room form for each room you want with js
  form.fields_for :room do |room_attributes|
    room_attributes.text_field :name
    # Dynamically add window_config forms on Room w/ JS
    room_attributes.fields_for :window_config do |window_attributes|
      window_attributes.select :window_id, Window.all
      window_attributes.select :lock_id, Lock.all
```